# How to share field data on multiple pages with ACF?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

Is there a way to create a group, populate its fields, and then use this data on any page of the site?

I already know how to share a field group on multiple pages, but then during the data insertion stage I have to populate the group with data separately on every page. That's laborious and not easily maintainable.

There must be some better solution, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You could buy the pro version, this enables global fields, sort of like a settings page that you'd get within a theme.

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/pro/

If you didn't want to do that you could create a group of fields and allow those fields only to be editable on a specific page like 'Page Global Elements'... then within your templates you could just call `<?php the_field('global_field', 132); ?>`

Comment: Thanks. I knew about the latter solution which is fine but semantically problematic ("feels" like a hack as the WP page would not be used as a page but as something else). About the former solution you mention I don't get it. I do own ACF Pro, could you explain how to set global fields?